# NodeRED - Connect ECONNREFUSED with multiples HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-red

We are encountering an issue when we are doing a lot of requests using **HTTP Request** on our NodeJS API server using **NodeRED**.

By the way, we also tested this using our [WWW Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-http-request) node which his implemented on the **Request library**. The result is the same :(

Here is the error stacktrace:

```
error:
  { message: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 163.113.172.80:1337',
    source:
     { id: '5d2aa78c.a2d558',
       type: 'http-request',
       name: undefined,
       count: 1 },
    stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 163.113.172.80:1337\n    at
    Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)\n    at
    exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)\n    at
    TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1062:14)' } }
```

Of course, we tested our API server using Apache Benchmark (ab CLI) with success (no failure) and an API Rate of 500 req/s.

**Technical information :**

- Node-RED version: v0.14.5
- Node.js  version: v5.5.0
- Windows_NT 6.1.7601 x64 LE
- Processor: Intel Xeon CPU E5-630 v3 3.70Ghz 8 Cores
- Memory: 64 Gb

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found an workaround by setting the max sockets value like this :

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 100;
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 100;
```

By default, the HTTP(S) global agent max socket value seems to be infinite...

Comment: I've recently just came across a similar issue with Node-RED, and using the built-in httprequest node, in terms of your settings, did you place these in the `settings.js` file?